# Restricting Angular URLS in spring security extension

Tags: spring, angular, spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I have integrated spring security saml extension with my angular 4 project. I am trying to restrict access to the URLs using the antmatchers in spring.

I want to let the user login if the url is like 
http://server:port/context/#/welcome

but when the user clicks logout button he will be redirected to #logout within the same page ( as this is an SPA). But because of the spring security rule even for the logout url, user is redirected to login.

How do I not restrict /#/logout url from requiring authentication. Here is my rule in spring security so far

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/#/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/loginFailed.jsp").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint())
                .and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresInsecure();
```

It will be a great help if anyone can tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: I think that you can't handle the URL from the SPA in the spring security once it's not requesting anything to the backend. You must let the user go to `http://server:port/context/` freely, and handle the user authentication in frontend. If the user is authenticated you can go to the other pages and when the user logout redirect it to logout page.

Comment: @LuizCarlos Actually when you want to logout using saml,  you make a get call to the url /saml/logout which initiates the logout process involving a couple of redirects and we also have a success logout handler which will redirect us to a specific URL which we can specify. I am trying to redirect to my /#/logout url. But when i redirect, it is redirecting me to login again. Thats the problem I am facing.